# Should questions about iTunes Connect be asked on Stack Overflow or here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, site-rec

For me, there have been several complications when I was working on an iPhone game that delayed my development time by almost an entire month, and that's because iTunes Connect is outright complicated. Half of it's intuitive, and the other half is broken.

Sometimes, review statuses and messages can be almost cryptic in my opinion, because I have no experience with it. For example, I couldn't find a button to Developer Reject my game because I had a bug in it the day I hit "Submit." (For those wondering why there was no button saying "Reject Binary" or something similar: **you have to wait 24 hours.**)

However, I don't know where to ask these sorts of questions.

- [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) is for problems with **coding**, not the actual release of the app.
- Ask Different is for questions regarding Apple devices.
- Programmers is for conceptual questions about programming.

It's not just iTunes Connect that people like me are having problems with; some might question the workings of developer technologies such as those at Google or Microsoft.

Some stuff simply isn't as easy as clicking a button saying "RELEASE MY APP INTO THE WILD AND GIVE ME MONEY!" This is still a step in the development process. Where do people like me ask questions about that?

(I'm asking this at the "Programmers" meta because that sounds like the most related site I know of for this question.)

Comment: [not here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/290011/modifying-paid-to-free-app-in-appstore-using-itunes-connect#comment600150_290011). Recommended reading: **[Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the [on topic points on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is:

> Apple services including iTunes Connect (selling music, books, apps)

You may want to check out the [existing questions with the itunes-connect tag](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/itunes-connect) and [their meta site](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/) first ([including three meta questions tagged with itunes-connect](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/itunes-connect)) before posting there to make sure your question fits into the community.

This would be off-topic here and on Stack Overflow, since [we aren't customer support for other companies](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think asking about iTunes Connect was customer service; I had legitimate questions that other developers had too.